# Evaluation of Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, perturbation-theory

How do I evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t/\tau} e^{i\omega t }dt$
Where $\tau$ is a constant

Comment: Do you want us to calculate it for you here, in a physics forum and *not* a maths forum?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux. I am aware that I should ask it in maths forum. I encountered the integration in Quantum Mechanics (Time dependent perturbation). Further I thought if someone helped to solve it it might help someone else who might stumble upon the same integration while learning the time dependent perturbation. Hope you understand my intention.

Comment: It does look like a fairly mundane physics type integral, so I'd be inclined to say it is reasonable here.

Comment: Note that the integrand is of the form $e^{at}$ where $a = i \omega - 1/\tau$.  And I assume you know how to integrate $e^{at}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0 ^\infty dt e^{-t/\tau}e^{i \omega t} = \int_0 ^\infty dt e^{-(1/\tau - i \omega)t}= -\frac{1}{1/\tau - i \omega} \left[ e^{-(1/\tau - i \omega)t}|_0^{\infty} \right] = \frac{1}{1/\tau - i \omega}$